# Doctrine 2 QueryBuilder vs Handcoded DQL - different results

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have Doctrine2 DQL query but I want to build it with QueryBuilder, I have noticed that produced DQL is somewhat different from the handcrafted one, and I'm wondering what am I missing here - maybe I'm not aware of something or doing things wrong way?

Ok, some details:

My handcrafted query looks like this:

```
select count(fi.id) 
from Entities\Content\FolderLookup fl 
join fl.site fls 
join fl.folder flf,
Entities\Content\FolderItem fi 
join fi.site fis 
join fi.folder fif 
join fi.item it 
join it.type tp 
join it.content ic 
where fl.namePath = ?1 
and tp.name = ?2 
and fls.id = fis.id 
and flf.id = fif.id
```

Now, I'm trying to reproduce it like this with QueryBuilder:

```
$qb->select("count(fi.id)")->from("Entities\Content\FolderLookup", "fl")->join("fl.site","fls")->join("fl.folder", "flf");

$qb->from("Entities\Content\FolderItem","fi")->join("fi.site","fis")->join("fi.folder","fif");
$qb->join("fi.item","it")->join("it.type","tp")->join("it.content","ic");

$wherePart = $qb->expr()->andx();
$wherePart->add($qb->expr()->eq("fl.namePath","?1"));
$wherePart->add($qb->expr()->eq("tp.name","?2"));
$wherePart->add($qb->expr()->eq("fls.id","fis.id"));
$wherePart->add($qb->expr()->eq("flf.id","fif.id"));

$qb->where($wherePart);
```

This however is producing this DQL query:

```
SELECT count(fi.id) FROM Entities\Content\FolderLookup fl, 
Entities\Content\FolderItem fi 
INNER JOIN fl.site fls 
INNER JOIN fl.folder flf 
INNER JOIN fi.site fis 
INNER JOIN fi.folder fif 
INNER JOIN fi.item it 
INNER JOIN it.type tp 
INNER JOIN it.content ic 
WHERE (fl.namePath = ?1) 
AND (tp.name = ?2) 
AND (fls.id = fis.id) 
AND (flf.id = fif.id)
```

As you can see there is part of this missing comapring to handcrafted one (First line):

```
fl join fl.site fls join fl.folder flf
```

I'm not sure why these joins are missing as I am defining them here:

```
$qb->select("count(fi.id)")->from("Entities\Content\FolderLookup", "fl")->join("fl.site","fls")->join("fl.folder", "flf");
```

**Update:**

The fun part starts, when DQL gets translated into SQL - in this case MySQL:

Handcrafted one becomes:

```
SELECT count(f0_.id) AS sclr0 FROM FolderLookup f1_ INNER JOIN Site s2_ ON f1_.site_id = s2_.id INNER JOIN Folder f3_ ON f1_.folder_id = f3_.id, FolderItem f0_ INNER JOIN Site s4_ ON f0_.site_id = s4_.id INNER JOIN Folder f5_ ON f0_.folder_id = f5_.id INNER JOIN Item i6_ ON f0_.item_id = i6_.id INNER JOIN ItemType i7_ ON i6_.type_id = i7_.id INNER JOIN ItemContent i8_ ON i6_.content_id = i8_.id WHERE f1_.namePath = ? AND i7_.name = ? AND s2_.id = s4_.id AND f3_.id = f5_.id
```

Where generated one looks like this:

```
SELECT count(f0_.id) AS sclr0 FROM FolderLookup f1_, FolderItem f0_ INNER JOIN Site s2_ ON f1_.site_id = s2_.id INNER JOIN Folder f3_ ON f1_.folder_id = f3_.id INNER JOIN Site s4_ ON f0_.site_id = s4_.id INNER JOIN Folder f5_ ON f0_.folder_id = f5_.id INNER JOIN Item i6_ ON f0_.item_id = i6_.id INNER JOIN ItemType i7_ ON i6_.type_id = i7_.id INNER JOIN ItemContent i8_ ON i6_.content_id = i8_.id WHERE (f1_.namePath = ?) AND (i7_.name = ?) AND (s2_.id = s4_.id) AND (f3_.id = f5_.id)
```

And this is invalid statement, as database returns with:

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'f1_.site_id' in 'on clause'
```

Any ideas welcome.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the DQL parser is wrongly positioning the joins to the wrong from.

My initial suggestion is to try to make only 1 FROM item and a subselect.
Also, I'd love if you add the same content you asked here in our bug tracking: http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC

Thanks a lot!

Guilherme Blanco
Doctirne Core Developer

Answer (score 0):

they are not missing. just reordered

> INNER JOIN fl.site fls 
>   INNER JOIN fl.folder flf

Comment: I have updated the post with some more information - I wonder why sql produced from these ones is different